# PHP DOM LoadXML processing infinite loop when xml has parse errors

Tags: php, dom, xml-parsing

How to stop the loop when xml data have parse errors?

```
//xml data <column><col>Col1</col><col>Col2</col><col>Col3</col><column>

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($item_xml);

//loads the data
// find column
if(!empty(   $xml->documentElement)){
   foreach(  $xml->documentElement->childNodes as $xmlChild){
          if($xmlChild->nodeName == 'column'){
             return $xmlChild;
         }
    }
}
```

If any XMl parse errors. it continuously process without throwing any exception.

How to avoid if xml parse errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/libxml_get_errors):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();

// Don't display errors and warnings
$errorState = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

// Load the XML now
$xml->loadXML($item_xml);

// Get all the errors, as an array
$errors = libxml_get_errors();

// If the array is not empty
if(!empty($errors)) {
    // Markup contains error(s)
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/127316)